# Is there a way to tell rebar not to run eunit tests for the dependencies?

Tags: erlang, rebar

When running:

```
./rebar eunit
```

the tests are run also for the external dependencies. Is there a way to change this behaviour? Maybe through the rebar.config file?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
./rebar eunit skip_deps=true
```

(or `recursive=false` with latest versions).

Comment: Cool. It works. I've tried to set that in the rebar.config ({skip_deps, true}. and {eunit, [{skip_deps, true}]}.) with no luck, though.

Comment: Note that `./rebar clean get-deps compile eunit skip_deps=true` doesn't work -- _why not_? Because `rebar` will skip *compile*-ing the dependencies, too!  Separate commands `./rebar clean get-deps compile` and `./rebar eunit skip_deps=true` works, though.

Answer (score 4):

You also can also use

```
./rebar eunit apps=your_app1,your_app2
```

This will run eunit test only for the specified applications.

Answer (score 3):

There is also an option to run tests only for specific application:

```
./rebar eunit app=app_name
```

Comment: That doesn't actually work for me. I'm using the latest snapshot of rebar from GitHub. Which version are you running?

Comment: @Roberto Alio: Strange. My version is "rebar version: 2 date: 20110714_102521 vcs: git df86768"